# how to debug a swf file

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm quite new to AS3 and now I need to solve a swf crash problem.

I have the source code and fla file, so I can debug/run it in FL, I can use trace to print out log. The problem is, on my machine, either run in FL or generated swf embed in IE works correctly. But the swf always crashes on tester's machine.

Because the swf is run in IE, trace seems doesn't work, so I'd like to know if there's any tool I can use so that I can see all the trace output on tester's machine.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Trace only works while working directly with Adobe Flash.

What you can do is call a javascript alert to display the Trace elements inside a BROWSER. Please note it will not work while directly opening the .swf

```
ExternalInterface.call("alert",output);
```

But their should be no different in handling any .swf except for the installed Version of the Flashplayer on each computer.

If it runs fine on your IE, then it should on the other as long as Flash Version and IE Version are the same.

Outdate Version usually lead to this sort of conflict.

Comment: `if(ExternalInterface.available){
    ExternalInterface.call("console.log",output);
}`